# jquery object need to fetch particular ID value from Ajax data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Using Ajax able to receive the data. Now need to fetch particular id value.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.userdetails', function () {
    var memberid = $(this)[0].id;

    var memberName = $("#memberName").val();

    var mydata = 'task=' + "memberdetail" + '&ID='
        + memberid + '&current_user=' + "<?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>"
        + '&username=' + username;

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/userrdetail.php',
        data: mydata,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('body').scrollTop(0);
            $(".loading").removeClass("hide");
        },

        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        }
```

Output:

```
<div>
  <h4>William Mark</h4>
  <input type="hidden" id="username" value="William Mark" name="username">  (999) 999-999   Ext: 454 &nbsp
    </p>
  </div>
```

Need to got id="username" value.

Comment: Maybe if you show us the PHP script called `userrdetail.php` we could be of some help to you

Comment: what do you want @salokh ?? , What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Right Now from userdetails I am able to display the output as : [code]<h4>William Mark</h4>
  <input type="hidden" id="username" value="William Mark" name="username">   [/code] I need to get the value of id="username" from the out.@pedram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Data attributes like :

```
<div id="454" data-info="content that need to displayed"></div>

$(document).on('click', '.userdetails', function () {
var memberid = $(this)[0].id;
var username=$(this).data('info');
var memberName = $("#memberName").val();
var mydata = 'task=' + "memberdetail" + '&ID='
    + memberid + '&current_user=' + "<?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>"
    + '&username=' + username;

$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/userrdetail.php',
    data: mydata,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('body').scrollTop(0);
        $(".loading").removeClass("hide");
    },

    success: function (data) {
    $("#username").html(username);                  
    $("#username").css({ 'display': "inline-block" });
    }
```